# Upgraded to windows 10 and now can't connect to sql server 2012

Tags: .net-framework, sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-10

I upgraded to Windows 10 on my laptop. I have opened SQL Server Management Studio, but it can't connect to the server.

I have looked at a few other questions, but nothing seems to work. I get the same error message as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026219/sql-server-2014-update-to-windows-10-and-cant-connect-to-the-local-server)

I also went to `Control Panel > Admin Tools > Services` and made sure SQL Server Browser is running.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: What does this have to do with C# or programming in general?

Comment: sorry thats a mistake

Comment: Anything to do with a firewall or closed ports? Try disabling your firewall for an attempt.

Comment: I have the standard windows 10 firewall. I switched it but didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the shared memory in SQL Server protocols? If it is disabled, you will not be able to connect to SQL Server in Windows 10.

On contrary, in Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 enabling the shared memory was often causing the same effect, so it is by the rule that it is often disabled. After upgrading to Windows 10 you might hit the issue as now it is required to be enabled... not sure why MSFT made this mess, but I have seen this issue quite often after upgrading to Windows 10

Run **SQL Server Configuration Manager** and then navigate to **SQL Server Native Client Configuration**

Check **Shared Memory** and if disabled, enable it

Try to connect SQL Server again